# Ensuring number has 2 numbers after decimal

Tags: jquery

I am using the following to calculate:

```
Math.round(parseInt(optionPrice * 100, 10) * eurRate) / 100;
```

Which in one instance returns:

```
68.4
```

How can I ensure the number is always returned like so:

```
68.40
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use javascripts `.toFixed()` method.

In you case, it would be `toFixed(2)`.
Where the number in bracket is the number of positions after decimal.

```
Eg:(Math.round(parseInt(optionPrice * 100, 10) * eurRate) / 100).toFixed(2);
```